# wifi network manager minimal distro

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

I have installed a minimal ubuntu distro on my eepc and the install xfce4, seems everything fine, but I can't find  a WIFI connection manager. I want a traditional one, with scan then connect and then ask for a password. It looks like there is not on the distro. How can I do that?

Comment: You probably need a driver for your wireless card. Please *edit* your question to include the output of `lspci -nn`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WICD or network-manager, wicd has less dependencies but the only disadvantage of it is that you can't use 3G.

To install them with a graphical front-end.

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome

sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk
```